# Having problem to migrate from fbv to cbv in django CreateView which my model is not submitted in my models

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to migrate from FBV to CBV and I encountered a problem which I completely don't know how to solve it, which is after enter a submit to insert a new news to my `model`, it doesn't do that, and it doesn't show anything. even **errors**. It just return to `create` page

## news/views

```py
from django.shortcuts import render , get_object_or_404
# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .models import PreNews

class NewsListView(ListView):
    
    model = PreNews
    template_name = 'news/main_news.html'
    queryset = PreNews.objects.order_by('-date')

class NewsDetailView(DetailView):
    
    model = PreNews
    template_name = 'news/sub_news.html'
    #slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
    
    def get_object(self):
        slug_ = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        return get_object_or_404(PreNews,slug=slug_)
        

class NewsCreateView(CreateView):
    
    model = PreNews
    template_name = 'create/news_create.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    succes_url = '/news/'
```

## news/models

```py
from django.db import models
from pages.models import LoginFormModel
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

class PreNews(models.Model):
    
    hardware = 'chw'
    software = 'csw'
    politics_iran = 'pir'
    politics_international = 'pin'
    news_choice = [
        (hardware,'computer hardware news'),
        (software,'computer software news'),
        (politics_iran,'iran politics'),
        (politics_international,'international politics'),
            ]
    
    author = models.ForeignKey('pages.LoginFormModel', on_delete = models.CASCADE ,)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=100,null=False)
    tags = models.TextField(default='sobhan esfandyari,')
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=3 , choices=news_choice , default=software)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=False,null=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    main_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=False)
    brief = models.TextField(max_length=255,null=False)
    article = models.TextField(null=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.title," ---- ",self.date.year ,self.date.month ,self.date.day ," ---- " ,self.date.hour ,":", self.date.minute," ---- ",self.author)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sub_news_url', kwargs = { 'slug' : self.slug ,'year' : self.date.year , 'month' : self.date.month , 'day' : self.date.day })
```

## news/urls

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import NewsListView , NewsDetailView , NewsCreateView
#app_name = 'news' ##
urlpatterns = [ 
    
    path('', NewsListView.as_view(), name='news'),
    path('create/', NewsCreateView.as_view(), name='news_create'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:slug>/', NewsDetailView.as_view(), name='sub_news_url'),
     ]
```

## template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en-US>

<head>

    <title>
        Sobhan Esfandyari Personal Website | DAWSHESSI
    </title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Contact Sobhan Esfandyari">
  <meta name="author" content="sobhanessi,Sobhan Esfandyari,Sobhan Esfandiari">
  <meta name="keywords" content="dawshessi, sobhanessi, sobhanesfandiari, Sobhan Esfandiari,Sobhan Esfandyari,sobhan esfandiari email,sobhanessi contact,sobhan esfandyari email,contact dawshessi,contact sobhanessi">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  {% load static %}
  <link href="{% static 'pages/newscreate.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="{% static 'pages/general.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body id="indexbody">
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
<br><br>

 <form style="width:auto%;" method='POST' action='' > {% csrf_token %}
 <div class="container">
    <div class="input-group" style="width:100%;">
      
      <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:20%;">Author</span>

      {{ form.author }}
      
    </div><br>
    
    <div class="input-group" style="width:100%;">
      
      <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:20%;">title</span>
      
      {{ form.title }}

    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group" style="width:100%;">
      
      <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:20%;">tags</span>
      {{ form.tags }}

    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group" style="width:100%;">
      
      <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:20%;">choice</span>

      {{ form.choice }}
      
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group" style="width:100%;">
      
      <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:20%;">slug</span>
      
      {{ form.slug }}

    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group" style="width:100%;">
      
      <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:20%;">main pic</span>

      {{ form.main_pic }}
      
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group" style="width:100%;">
      
      <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:20%;">brief</span>
      
      {{ form.brief }}

    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group" style="width:100%;">
      
      <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:20%;">article</span>
      
      {{ form.article }}

    </div>
    <br>
    
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
</div>
</form>
{% include 'footer.html' %}

</body>

</html>
```

I want to submit a new `news` in my `models` and redirect to main news page or even the news which I have just created.

Comment: A model is not a form, but an "entity", so a model name `LoginFormModel` makes not much sense. Especially since Django has already something in place for users: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/

Comment: I changed the `ForeignKey `part to `auth.User` but stll not working. I mean it doesn't show any **error** it return to `create` page and didn't insert any news to my `models`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is `ImageField` which needs `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the template